# Meaning of 1 in setcookie("test", "PHP-Hypertext-Preprocessor", time()+60, "/location", 1);

Tags: php, cookies

I understand all other args but i cant understand  meaning of 1 in following code

```
 setcookie("test", "PHP-Hypertext-Preprocessor", time()+60, "/location", 1);
```

Comment: Probably a mistake, as the sixth argument determines whether to use a secure connection or not. The fifth, like in your example is for the domain. Btw, there is a huge library of PHP functions and corresponding explanations on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: [php.net/setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). As Jan said, you're missing an argument. Last two possible boolean arguments are `$secure` and `$httponly`.

Comment: it is the example from Wikipedia  So how it can be mistake

Comment: @AlienArtSoftware So you think Wikipedia is *always always* right then? Hmm... just for reference: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2131458/Up-articles-Wikipedia-contain-factual-errors.html

Comment: You'll have a better time reading the PHP docs than wikipedia as a reference for the language. The PHP docs are comprehensive and will explain every parameter.

Comment: i think example is right see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34401451/5700136

Comment: Thanks for suggestion  @noahnu

Comment: Take a look at the function description in the [docs](http://php.net/setcookie). The square brackets means the parameter is optional. Square brackets can be nested to indicate for example that if you choose to include `$expire`, you **must** include `$value`. Likewise, the string `$domain` is required before booleans `$secure` or `$httponly`. Side note: Wikipedia claims `setcookie has 1 more optional argument, not used here` which is blatantly false (just look at the docs, there are more than 1).

Answer (score 0):

From [php.net/setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

**secure**

> Indicates that the cookie should only be transmitted over a secure
>   HTTPS connection from the client. When set to TRUE, the cookie will
>   only be set if a secure connection exists. On the server-side, it's on
>   the programmer to send this kind of cookie only on secure connection
>   (e.g. with respect to $_SERVER["HTTPS"]).

The `1`, which means `secure = true` will make sure the cookie will be sent from the client only if the transmission is over `https` protocol.

On the server side you should check to make sure the cookie is only transmitted over `https` (e.g. using `$_SERVER["HTTPS"]`)

Edit: just noticed you are missing an argument?